# How can I set Adobe Flash Player to update automatically?

Tags: updates, flash, flash-player

Whenever Adobe releases an update to Flash Player, I get prompted to download and install the new version. I tried to find a way to set it to automatically apply updates whenever they were available, without any luck. I searched the Adobe forums, and most of the answers I found describe how to enable/disable checks for new versions.

I want to have my Flash Player up-to-date at all times, but I don't want to click through several download and installation screens every few weeks.

Is there a way to set it to auto-update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this method lacks finesse, it works:

1. Go to [Ninite](http://ninite.com/), scroll down and select both Flash Flash plugins (IE and non-IE):
   [image: Ninite]
2. Ninite will spit out an installer file. Download and run it to see how it works. *In theory*, if you Flash plugins are up to date, Ninite will skip installation.
3. Open **Task Scheduler** and [setup a task](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/12444-task-scheduler-create-new-task.html) that runs this Ninite installer program every day.

Caveat: This method may fail if your browser is currently open.

Comment: George, Ninite is awesome! Your method has enough finesse for me. Marked as answer and will +1 as soon as I get enough rep.

Comment: Sadly but this feature now only in Ninite Pro and its cost 20$ per month. https://ninite.com/applist/pro.html

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has not provided a method, their tool only allows the notifications to be enabled or disabled.

Comment: I'll +1 your answer as soon as I get enough rep. I'll mark it as the answer unless somebody else knows a workaround.